# Test classes pass in validation before deploy, but fail when i run them from "Apex Test Execution"

Tags: failing-tests

I have a few apex test class, that pass when i run them while deploying a change set, but when i run them from the setup, in "Apex Test Execution", they fail with the error `MIXED_DML_OPERATION`
(the reason this error pops is because we have a user workflow that does an unnecessary update)

Why the errors don't appear in deployment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

During deployment, Mixed DML operations checks are skipped. Here is a knowledge article regarding this: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000231160&type=1